# Cannot extend existing data disk over 2TB on windows 2008 with dynamic and gpt part

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage-area-network, lun

As my D: disk is almost full (2TB) I extended the FC lun to 2.5TB.
The new 500Go are seen by windows as "Unalloacted" as expected.

I tried to extend the volume but windows says

```
There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation
```

I read on the web that the disk should be configured as GPT and as a dynamic but it's already a dynamic GPT disk.

How can I extend my disk without any data loss? My operating system is Windows 2008 R2 x64 SP1 and the SAN is a 3PAR

Answer (score 4):

Solved!

I had to do a "Rescan disks" and then the extension worked!

Comment: Solved indeed!, rescan of the disk was the trick!
Many thanks